# joomla- js file calling

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/eurostar/js/jquery-1.5.min.js" /></script>
```

any error?

but if I just type `<` which file automatically closing again and again,

Why repeating this closing tag -   `</script> </script> </script>`

Comment: Uhm, not really clear...Anyway, you're self-closing the <script> tag here ( /></script>), should be <script.....></script>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here.  It looks like you're attempting to include jQuery, which won't work well in Joomla.

Comment: @SomeKittens: That's wrong! Joomla works fine with jQuery. You just need to take care of your JS code.

Comment: "Needing to rewrite a major portion of your code" != "works fine."  ESPECIALLY if you're just blatantly including it like I think @Hunter is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

slash

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/eurostar/js/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `jquery-1.5.min.js" /></script>`
`jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>`